# Issues in deploying Cloud foundry with BOSHLite on laptop

Tags: deployment, cloud-foundry, bosh-deployer

```
$ bosh deploy

Acting as user 'admin' on deployment 'cf-warden' on 'Bosh Lite Director'
Getting deployment properties from director...
Unable to get properties list from director, trying without it...
Release 'cf' not found on director. Unable to resolve 'latest' alias in manifest.
```

**Other Info**

- I named the release `mgdev` when creating it (as it was showing CF | when it prompted for release name)
- Output from `bosh releases`:

  ```
  $ bosh releases
  Acting as user 'admin' on 'Bosh Lite Director'

  +-------+----------+-------------+
  | Name  | Versions | Commit Hash | 
  +-------+----------+-------------+
  | mgdev | 0+dev.1  |     3c73e6d | 
  +-------+----------+-------------+
  Releases total: 1
  ```
- I see `cf-release/dev-releases/mgdev/mgdev-0+dev.1.yml` and `index.yml` files.

  - Q: `bosh deploy` should use these files? If yes, how and what would be the command?
  - Q: Is this right to execute?`bosh upload release /dev-releases/mgdev/mgdev-0+dev.1.yml`
- Output from `bosh properties`:

  ```
  $ bosh properties

  Acting as user 'admin' on deployment 'cf-warden' on 'Bosh Lite Director'
  Target Bosh Lite Director
  Deployment cf-warden

  Error 70000: Deployment `cf-warden' doesn't exist
  ```

Comment: The same problem. Have you resolved it?

Answer (score 1):

Based on info you provided, it seems that you have a release `mgdev` but not `cf`. Hence, `bosh deploy` cannot resolve `cf:latest` to a valid release. You probably wanna change release name in your release manifest to `cf`, if that's the cf release you're trying to deploy.

To address other two questions:

1. `bosh deploy` is going to use **deployment manifest** but NOT release manifest
2. Yes that's correct, you can upload release using either manifest or tarball

Answer (score 0):

During `bosh create release` it asks for release name and after it will be added to some yaml-config (I mean additional `bosh create release` will not help you as it already is in some yaml). If you already typed own one, remove that pre-config yaml (try to find it with `grep -nr typed_release_name *` for example).

If you don't want all these stuff, just press `Enter` when `bosh create release` asks you for release name and it automatically places `cf` there.

```
$ bosh create release
Syncing blobs...
debian_nfs_server/nfs-kernel-server_1%3a1... downloaded
uaa/cloudfoundry-identity-varz-1.0.2.war downloaded
...
java-buildpack/java-buildpack-offline-v3.... downloaded
Please enter development release name: |cf| <just type Enter here>
```

PS. Also you can try to change manifest name in `bosh status`, I suppose it is changed during `./scripts/generate-bosh-lite-dev-manifest`

Answer (score 0):

bosh.io has a bunch of releases, you can just referance the URL to load the release into director, you don't need to download a tarball or anything bosh will do it all..

```
bosh upload release http://bosh.io/d/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/garden-runc-release?v=1.0.0
```

but, guoger is right (above) the names must match in the deployment manifest to the releases you have...

```
bosh releases
```

will show your installed releases.... Just make sure they match the manifest and your all set.